# How to find FFT in Excel without using Fourier Analysis function?

Tags: excel, matlab, filter, fft, data-representation

I am trying to write an FFT application in Excel that claculates frequencies, amplitude and phase. I know how to use the in-built function but the data I am trying to analyse has 32,795 points, more than the maximum 4096 for the in-buit function.

Does anyone know how I can either (1) Increase the maximum number of data inputs? (2) Write my own macro to avoid using the in-built function (if this allows me to analyse all the points)? or (3) Start over in Matlab or a with programming language that allows me to analyse all the points and get all the data I need?

Comment: MATLAB (or free clone Octave) is probably the best way to go.

Comment: If you are more specific about the problem you like to solve, then you'll get better responses. E.g. why is it important to analyze the whole sequence in one FFT.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use the matlab built in function and it doesnt have the limitation like Excel and then import the results to excel

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Excel FFT has the limit of data point 4096 and slow.

I programmed FFT using only Excel VBA code and there is no limit of the data point.

Below is the performance for the data point count.
There was a part where I could speed it up a bit, but I didn't b/c it makes the code less readable. However, even now, it may be the fastest FFT code in the Excel.

[data point]     [FFT execution time]

```
 4 kB             62ms    

 16 kB            235ms    

 64 kB            984ms
```

- Computer Specification: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz

I implemented Cooley-Tukey algorithm, and use several techniques to speed-up the code running time in the Excel environment.

You can find the code and download the excel file in here. (https://infograph.tistory.com/351)

Otherwise you can review main logic as below:

```
'Module: fftProgram
'Author: HJ Park
'Date  : 2019.5.18(v1.0), 2022.8.1(v2.0)

Option Explicit

Public Const myPI As Double = 3.14159265358979

Public Function Log2(X As Long) As Double
  Log2 = Log(X) / Log(2)
End Function

Public Function Ceiling(ByVal X As Double, Optional ByVal Factor As Double = 1) As Double
    ' X is the value you want to round
    ' Factor is the multiple to which you want to round
    Ceiling = (Int(X / Factor) - (X / Factor - Int(X / Factor) > 0)) * Factor
End Function

Public Function Floor(ByVal X As Double, Optional ByVal Factor As Double = 1) As Double
    ' X is the value you want to round
    ' Factor is the multiple to which you want to round
    Floor = Int(X / Factor) * Factor
End Function

' return 0 if N is 2^n value,
' return (2^n - N) if N is not 2^n value. 2^n is Ceiling value.
' return -1, if error
Public Function IsPowerOfTwo(N As Long) As Long
  If N = 0 Then GoTo EXIT_FUNCTION
  
  Dim c As Long, F As Double
  c = Ceiling(Log2(N)) 'Factor=0, therefore C is an integer number
  F = Floor(Log2(N))
  
  If c = F Then
    IsPowerOfTwo = 0
  Else
    IsPowerOfTwo = (2 ^ c - N)
  End If
  Exit Function
  
EXIT_FUNCTION:
  IsPowerOfTwo = -1
End Function




''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Function MakePowerOfTwoSize(ByRef r As Range, ByVal fillCount As Long) As Boolean
  Dim arr() As Integer
  On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLE
  
  '1)make a array with zero
  ReDim arr(0 To fillCount - 1) As Integer
    
  '2)set a range to be filled with zero
  Dim fillRowStart As Long
  Dim fillRange As Range
  
  fillRowStart = r.Row + r.Rows.Count
  Set fillRange = Range(Cells(fillRowStart, r.Column), Cells(fillRowStart + fillCount - 1, r.Column))
  
  '3)fill as zero
  fillRange = arr
  
  '4)update range area to be extended
  Set r = Union(r, fillRange)
  
  MakePowerOfTwoSize = True
  Exit Function
  
ERROR_HANDLE:
  MakePowerOfTwoSize = False
End Function

' read the range and return it as complex value array
Function Range2Array(r As Range) As Complex()
  Dim i As Long, size As Long
  Dim arr() As Complex
  
  size = r.Rows.Count
  ReDim arr(0 To size - 1) As Complex
  
  Dim re As Double, im As Double
  
  On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLE
  For i = 1 To size
    arr(i - 1) = String2Complex(r.Rows(i).Value)
  Next i
  
  Range2Array = arr
  
  Exit Function
ERROR_HANDLE:
  MsgBox "Error: " & i
End Function

Function ArrangedNum(num As Long, numOfBits As Integer) As Long
  Dim arr() As Byte
  Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
  Dim k As Long
  
  If (2 ^ numOfBits) <= num Then GoTo EXIT_FUNCTION
  
  '1) Decimal number -> Reversed Binary array : (13,4) -> {1,1,0,1} -> {1,0,1,1}
  ReDim arr(0 To numOfBits - 1) As Byte
  For i = 0 To numOfBits - 1
    j = (numOfBits - 1) - i
    k = Int((num / (2 ^ j)))
    arr(j) = (k And 1)
  Next i
  
  '2) Reversed Binary -> Decimal: {1,0,1,1} -> 1*2^3 + 0*2^2 + 1*2&1 + 1 = 11
  Dim d As Long
  For i = 0 To numOfBits - 1
    d = d + (arr(i) * 2 ^ (numOfBits - 1 - i))
  Next i
  
  ArrangedNum = d
  Exit Function
  
EXIT_FUNCTION:
  ArrangedNum = 0
End Function

' rangeArr[1 to n, 1]
Function arrangeToFFTArray(arr() As Complex, size As Long, numOfBits As Integer) As Complex()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  Dim arrangedArr() As Complex
    
  ReDim arrangedArr(0 To size - 1) As Complex
  For i = 0 To size - 1
    j = ArrangedNum(i, numOfBits)  '{000,001,010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111} -> {0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7}
    arrangedArr(j) = arr(i)
  Next i
  
  arrangeToFFTArray = arrangedArr
End Function

' calculate convolution ring W
' W[k] = cos(theta) - isin(theta)
'   theta = (2pi*k/N)
Function CalculateW(cnt As Long, isInverse As Boolean) As Complex()
  Dim arr() As Complex
  Dim i As Long
  Dim T As Double, theta As Double
  Dim N As Long, N2 As Long
  
  N = cnt
  N2 = N / 2
  ReDim arr(0 To N2 - 1) As Complex  'enough to calculate 0 to (N/2 -1)
  T = 2 * myPI / CDbl(N)
  
  If isInverse Then
    For i = 0 To N2 - 1
      theta = -(T * i)
      arr(i) = Cplx(Cos(theta), -Sin(theta))
    Next i
  Else
    For i = 0 To N2 - 1
      theta = T * i
      arr(i) = Cplx(Cos(theta), -Sin(theta))
    Next i
  End If
  
  CalculateW = arr
End Function

' X({0,1}, [0,n-1]): 2d array.  (0, n) <--> (1,n)
' src: src index of the array. 0 or 1
' tgt: tgt index of the array. 1 or 0
' s : starting index of the data in the array
' size: region size to be calculated
' kJump : k's jumping value
' W(0 ~ n-1) : Convolution ring
Sub RegionFFT(X() As Complex, src As Integer, tgt As Integer, _
            s As Long, size As Long, kJump As Long, W() As Complex)
  Dim i As Long, e As Long
  Dim half As Long
  Dim k As Long
  Dim T As Complex
  
  ' Xm+1[i] = Xm[i] + Xm[i+half]W[k]
  ' Xm+1[i+half] = Xm[i] - Xm[i+half]W[k]
  k = 0
  e = s + (size / 2) - 1
  half = size / 2
  For i = s To e
    T = CMult(X(src, i + half), W(k))
    X(tgt, i) = CAdd(X(src, i), T)
    X(tgt, i + half) = CSub(X(src, i), T)
    k = k + kJump
  Next i
End Sub

Sub WriteToTarget(tgtRange As Range, X() As Complex, tgtIdx As Integer, N As Long, roundDigit As Integer)
  Dim i As Long
  Dim arr() As Variant
  
  ReDim arr(0 To N - 1) As Variant
  For i = 0 To N - 1
   If X(tgtIdx, i).im < 0 Then
     arr(i) = Round(X(tgtIdx, i).re, roundDigit) & Round(X(tgtIdx, i).im, roundDigit) & "i"
   Else
     arr(i) = Round(X(tgtIdx, i).re, roundDigit) & "+" & Round(X(tgtIdx, i).im, roundDigit) & "i"
   End If
  Next i
  
  tgtRange.Rows = Application.Transpose(arr)
End Sub

' xRange: input data
' tgtRange: output range
' isInverse: FFT or IFFT
Public Function FFT_Forward(xRange As Range, tgtRangeStart As Range, roundDigit As Integer, isInverse As Boolean) As Complex()
  Dim i As Long, N As Long
  Dim totalLoop As Integer, curLoop As Integer 'enough as Integer b/c it is used for loop varoable
  Dim xArr() As Complex, xSortedArr() As Complex
  Dim W() As Complex 'convolution ring
  Dim X() As Complex 'output result
  Dim errMsg As String
  
  errMsg = "Uncatched error"
    
  '1) check whether 2^r count data, if not pad to zero
  Dim fillCount As Long
  N = xRange.Rows.Count
  fillCount = IsPowerOfTwo(N)
  If fillCount = -1 Then
    errMsg = "No input data. Choose input data"
    GoTo ERROR_HANDLE
  End If
  If fillCount <> 0 Then
    If MakePowerOfTwoSize(xRange, fillCount) = False Then  'xRange's size will be chnaged
      errMsg = "Error while zero padding"
      GoTo ERROR_HANDLE
    End If
  End If
  
  '2) calculate loop count for FFT: 2->1  4->2  8->3 ...
  N = xRange.Rows.Count 'xRange's size can be changed so read one more...
  totalLoop = Log2(N)
  
  '3) sort x for 2's FFT : convert to reversed binary and then convert to decimal
  xArr = Range2Array(xRange)  'xArr[0,n-1]
  xSortedArr = arrangeToFFTArray(xArr, N, totalLoop) 'xSortedArr[0,n-1]
  
  '4) calculate W
  W = CalculateW(N, isInverse)
  
  '5) use 2-dimensional array to save memory space. X[0, ] <-> X[1, ]
  ReDim X(0 To 1, 0 To N - 1) As Complex
  For i = 0 To N - 1
    X(0, i) = xSortedArr(i)
  Next i
  
  '6) Do 2's FFT with sorted x
  Dim srcIdx As Integer, tgtIdx As Integer
  Dim kJump As Long, regionSize As Long
  
  tgtIdx = 0
  For curLoop = 0 To totalLoop - 1
    tgtIdx = (tgtIdx + 1) Mod 2
    srcIdx = (tgtIdx + 1) Mod 2
    regionSize = 2 ^ (curLoop + 1)          ' if N=8: 2 -> 4 -> 8
    kJump = 2 ^ (totalLoop - curLoop - 1)    ' if N=8: 4 -> 2 -> 1
    i = 0
    Do While i < N
      Call RegionFFT(X, srcIdx, tgtIdx, i, regionSize, kJump, W)
      i = i + regionSize
    Loop
  Next curLoop
  
  '7)return the value
  Dim resultIdx As Integer
  If (totalLoop Mod 2) = 0 Then resultIdx = 0 Else resultIdx = 1
  
  Dim result() As Complex
  ReDim result(0 To N - 1) As Complex
  If isInverse = True Then
    For i = 0 To N - 1
      result(i) = CDivR(X(resultIdx, i), N)
    Next i
  Else
    For i = 0 To N - 1
      result(i) = X(resultIdx, i)
    Next i
  End If
  
  FFT_Forward = result
  
  Exit Function
  
ERROR_HANDLE:
  Err.Raise Number:=vbObjectError, Description:=("FFT calculation error: " & errMsg)
End Function


Public Sub FFT(xRange As Range, tgtRangeStart As Range, roundDigit As Integer)
  Dim X() As Complex
  Dim tgtRange As Range
  
  '1. calculate FFT_forward value
  On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLE
  X = FFT_Forward(xRange, tgtRangeStart, roundDigit, False)
  
  '2. write to the worksheet
  Dim N As Long
  N = UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1
  
  Dim i As Long
  Dim arr() As Variant
  ReDim arr(0 To N - 1) As Variant
  For i = 0 To N - 1
   If X(i).im < 0 Then
     arr(i) = Round(X(i).re, roundDigit) & Round(X(i).im, roundDigit) & "i"
   Else
     arr(i) = Round(X(i).re, roundDigit) & "+" & Round(X(i).im, roundDigit) & "i"
   End If
  Next i
  
  Set tgtRange = Range(Cells(tgtRangeStart.Row, tgtRangeStart.Column), Cells(tgtRangeStart.Row + N - 1, tgtRangeStart.Column))
  tgtRange.Rows = Application.Transpose(arr)
  Exit Sub
  
ERROR_HANDLE:
  
End Sub

Public Sub IFFT(xRange As Range, tgtRangeStart As Range, roundDigit As Integer)
  Dim X() As Complex
  Dim tgtRange As Range
  
  '1. calculate FFT_forward value
  On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLE
  X = FFT_Forward(xRange, tgtRangeStart, roundDigit, True)
  
  '2.write to the worksheet
  Dim N As Long
  N = UBound(X) - LBound(X) + 1
  
  Dim arr() As Variant
  ReDim arr(0 To N - 1) As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  For i = 0 To N - 1
    arr(i) = Round(X(i).re, roundDigit)
  Next i
  
  Set tgtRange = Range(Cells(tgtRangeStart.Row, tgtRangeStart.Column), Cells(tgtRangeStart.Row + N - 1, tgtRangeStart.Column))
  tgtRange.Rows = Application.Transpose(arr)
  Exit Sub
  
ERROR_HANDLE:

End Sub


Sub LoadFFTForm()
  FFT_Form.Show
```

Comment: Slow??? How come. I ran a 4096 data points M$™FFT 10 minutes ago and it's still unfinished, eating 100% CPU of a i7-10510U @2.30 GHz. And you say you can do it with VBA in 62ms? Are you saying M$ is a piece of crap? Are you? Yeah. You didn't, that's right. I did.

Answer (score 0):

In alternative to the VBA solution from HeeJin, with `LAMBDA` functions in recent versions of Excel it is possible to implement the FFT as a pure formula (i.e. without VBA).

One such implementation is https://github.com/altomani/XL-FFT.

For power of two length it uses a recursive radix-2 [Cooley-Tukey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm)
and for other length a version of [Bluestein's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_Z-transform) that reduces the calculation to a power of two case.