# Convert Excel VBA Analysis ToolPack "Fourier" Sub into a UDF Function

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I would like to create a UDF in VBA making use of Excel's "Fourier" sub available in ATPVBAEN.XLAM Analysis ToolPack VBA. I thought a way to do this would be to create on the fly a new WorkSheet, run the sub with the output directed to that new Worksheet, copy the results into an array, delete the created worksheet, and return the array. However, I seem to have run into a problem where I cannot create a new WorkSheet in a call from a function in the workbook; a call to the following function from a cell in the workbook does not create a new worksheet:

```
Function addWS() As Variant
  Dim WS As Worksheet
  With ThisWorkbook
    Set WS = .Worksheets.Add
  End With
End Function
```

How do I overcome this?

Comment: Use a **Sub** rather than a **UDF()**

Comment: and how do I call a Sub from a worksheet?...

Comment: You can't...you need to re-structure your approach.

Comment: Thanks, but I have to implement it as a UDF. Other suggestions?

Comment: **You can't add a sheet through UDF**.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel

Comment: Thanks. So, how to wrap this sub then?

Answer (score 0):

You can't transform the ToolPack's Fourier Transform into a UDF.

You can however implement the Fourier transform in some other way.

1. Define a UDF in VBA (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73348983/1848641) and the [linked code](https://infograph.tistory.com/351).
2. Use the recently released Excel LAMBDA functions to define a new custom function (see e.g. [this repository](https://github.com/altomani/XL-FFT)).